# which option is good wheather alarm manager or async adapter in android

Tags: android, server

hi guys i am making a app in which i want to store latitude and longitude at server. where ever user moves after every 5 minutes the coordinates are send to my server.so i am confuse what t use a alarm manager or sync adapter.also this task continues even the user close the app.also i want know what is the lifetime of a service. means if i have stated a service will that be running when app close/killed.
also whats impact on battery power in alarm manager,sync adapter,service.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This exact question has been asked not too long ago... and seems to be asked once every month or two. Seems like a lot of people want to track their friends... or stalk them, or whatever. Google a bit. Try a few things. Then come back here with specific questions, but don't expect anyone to write the entire app for you, please.

Comment: i just need a direction man

Comment: Then go the google way.

Comment: google bought me here

Answer (score 0):

From what I have heard Alarm Manager is not recommended for life-time operations like ticking etc. so I think it would be better to use service in your APP. You can use *wakeLock* for your app to prevent the phone from falling asleep during doing some work